stack-use-after-return with projection to a member inside a ranges pipeline
I have a struct containing a member int:
struct S {
    int i;
};

and a function that returns an instance of this struct, constructed from an int:
S f(int) {
    return {42};
}

and I'm using this function in a ranges pipeline:
auto r = std::views::iota(5, 10) 
       | std::views::transform(&f) 
       | std::views::transform(&S::i);

This seems fine, and doing something like std::ranges::size(r) works.
However, when I try to access any of the elements of r, I get a stack-use-after-free error from address sanitizer:
auto n = r.front(); // ==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-return on address ...

This happens with both Clang and GCC. What am I doing wrong here?

Replacing the transform using &S::i with a transform using a lambda makes the address sanitizer error go away:
auto r = std::views::iota(5, 10) 
       | std::views::transform(&f)
       | std::views::transform([](S const & s) {
            return s.i;
        });

auto n = r.front(); // no error

If there is some lifetime issue with the S objects returned from f I would expect the same issue to occur in this case. Why is there a difference here between using a lambda and a projection to a member?

Could you show a [mcve]?

You apply &S::i to temporary, with lifetime shorter that we might expect from user point of view :/

@JeJo Hmm, that sort of makes sense. Though I feel like I've written these pipelines before without running into this issue. Not sure if the "full expression" part is correct, since piping it to ranges::to should work in that case, but it doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/Evqo75r58 Probably Jarod42's comment is more correct, and it's within  the pipeline that the Ss don't live long enough.

Hmm, if I replace the &S::i with a lambda taking a S const & address-sanitizer doesn't complain anymore https://godbolt.org/z/njWq9axeP. Shouldn't the lambda version have the same issue? (Might just be asan not detecting the bug, of course).

You return by value, not by reference Demo... Even if original would be more like that.

@Jarod42 Oh, that makes more sense now (thanks for the demo). So I guess there's no way to get the effect I want with member projections? That's very frustrating, the code looks completely sane to me (and equivalent to the lambda version that returns by value).

See in another way, composition of your transform would be [](int /* from iota */) -> int& { S s{42};return s.i; } where dangling is more visible.
